# Sub GBP £250 Android 'phone with long battery life - as of June 2021

Tags: android, smartphones, cheap

Only 2 things really interest me - long battery life & cost - sub £250 ~= US $ 350, Eur 290 .

I am replacing an old UleFone Power which had an 1100maH battery (!). I don't care that it was a brick - I loved it.

I use my 'phone for Email, WhatsApp, SMS and occasional 'phone calls & to browse, generally to read the news.

I *never* play games, stream videos, use any social networks, listen to music, etc. And I don't care too much about camera quality.

A reasonable amount of memory would be nice (NFC would be a bonus, but I don't expect it).

I have no problems with non-mainstream brands. What can you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I bought a [Samsung M31](https://en.gsm.cool/specs/samsung-galaxy-m31) in the end - and am very pleased with it. As news, it would have been too expensive, but it was released the previous February, so had been around for 16 months, causing the price to drop into my range.

[image]

---

---

In the meantime though, UleFone have released [one with a 13,200 mh battery](https://www.ulefone.com/power-armor-13.html), which I would probably have bought had it been available when my last one died.